# Suspense loading icon on every update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-suspense

I have the following React component:

```
const Bleh = (props: any) => {
    const [val, setVal] = React.useState("")
    return <div>
        <Icon
            style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}
            iconName="style-three-pin-circle"
            iconColor="orange"
        />
        <Input value={val} onChange={setVal} style={{ width: 200 }} />
    </div>
}
```

When I type something into input val the Icon which is suspense loaded goes in and out of a suspense state.

Is there a way to skip the suspense state if the icons internal assets were already loaded?

Comment: What is the `Input` component?  Normally onChange events return the event as the argument to the function

Comment: simple custom input wrapper which takes the string from the onchange nad passes it down

Comment: Can you show the code where Icon and Input come from?